# Can I do Aspect Oriented Programming in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, aop

Whether this question is a wide range or not I would like to ask :
Is it possible to implement aspect-oriented programming (AOP) features into OCaml language?

Comment: The point here is why will you ever want to do that? `functional programming` is already enough to conquer everything

Comment: Perhaps, I asked wrongly I really care that this language supports separation of concern principle or not?

Comment: what specifically are you looking for? modules, first-class module support and functors should be enough to describe the separation of concerns. Is there some other "design pattern" that you're looking for?

Comment: I only consider modules, also i am not familiar with OCaml, I just wanted to ask the possibility of implementation of AOP.

Comment: There is a paper regarding Aspectual Caml, but I did not find it convincing and it hasn't gain traction as far as I know. PPX or CAMLP4 would also be of importance to manipulate the AST. I'm not sure if it could support regex-pattern matching for point-cuts.

Comment: OCaml is not a pure language, you can expose mutability-based "add advice" to your functions. You can also do this in a functional manner, by lifting everything into a monad.

Comment: I think the issue that still stands is what AOP means in a functional programming context. AOP has a number of different ways to accomplish the abstraction of cross-cutting-concerns. Hyper/J is compile based, composing subsets of the application. This is easily done in OCaml and the build system. The other is AspectJ which manipulates the AST of the application based on point-cuts and pattern matching on types. As mentioned, this can probably be done my PPX. But, does FP even warrant a different paradigm of separating CCC or does the philosophy itself provide that ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > It is interesting to observe that, in contrast to the traditional
> >     concept of crosscutting in the OO setting where aspects typically
> >     crosscut several classes, the majority of the applications of aspects
> >     in functional programming only involve a single function in the
> >     pointcut. We believe the realisation of this difference as concluded
> >     by this paper is important to both the functional and AOP commu- nity.
> >     **There is a pressing need to properly interpret and develop of the
> >     concept of ‘crosscutting’ in the functional setting** before functional AOP spreads its wings. 
> >     *[emphasis mine]*
>
> [What Does Aspect-Oriented Programming Mean for Functional Programmers?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.205.1699) (PDF)

Regardless, there are direct attempts/translations of AOP to OCaml or ML systems. From my comment, I don't find these convincing, and believe that proper use of modules and functors can do a lot to capture the demarcation of concerns. Those direct attempts are,

- [Aspectual Caml](http://prg.is.titech.ac.jp/projects/aspectual-caml/)
- [PolyAml(PDF)](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1052&context=cis_reports)
- [Aspect ML](http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/projects/aspectml/)